# CSRF verification failed on submit after rendering the template via Ajax before

Tags: django, ajax, csrf

I have a large model formset with initial data, which is injected by ajax through a seperates rendered template. I also pass the csrf token to the template. In the inspector you can also see that the csrf hidden input looks exactly like the other forms on the same page. However, if I want to submit the form, I still get a csrf error.

So the complete interface works and also the token is rendered into the template, only I can't submit the form and I don't know why

I already tried to render the form without input and inject the inputs via Ajax, but the result was the same.

### views.py that is called by ajax POST request

```py
def render_revolver_table_form(request, product_id, production_step):
    context = {}
    context['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = request.POST.dict()['csrfmiddlewaretoken']
    template = 'products/product_details/setup_revolver_table.html'

    SetupRevolverMapFormSet = modelformset_factory(SetupRevolverMap, exclude=(
        'product', 'production_step', 'kanal', 'id'), form=SetupRevolverMapForm)
    setup_revolver_maps = SetupRevolverMap.objects.filter(
        product=product_id, production_step=production_step).all()
    context['formset'] = SetupRevolverMapFormSet(
        queryset=setup_revolver_maps.filter(kanal=1))

    return render(request, template, context)
```

### injected template

```html
<table class="table">
   <thead class="thead-dark">
      <tr>
         <!-- Here is content from the formset -->
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <form id="setup_revolver_form_kanal_1" action="" method="POST">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value={{csrfmiddlewaretoken}}" />
      {{ formset.management_form  }}
      <tbody>
         <!-- Here is content from the formset -->
      </tbody>
   </form>
</table>
```

### ajax.js

```
csrftoken = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#setup_revolver').append(data))
    }
});
```

### template.html

```html
 <!-- other forms etc. -->
 <div id="setup_revolver">
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about `_get_new_csrf_token` ? Where does it come from and what does it do ?

Comment: You need to set your CSRF in your header

Comment: Sorry fixed the _get_new_csrf_token. I already tried to put the token in the header but nothing has changed. If I try to render the form with ```{% csrf_token %}```, the token value on the hidden input is a different as in the other forms.